# GCM notifications not comming in certain device

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have curious problem. I have written my own android application, which getting some notifications from desktop CRM system through GCM. I tested it on two cell phones:
1- LG D320 with Android 4.4
2- Sony Xperia SP with Android 4.3

Problem is, that notification is comming only other devices then in Sony Xperia. I tried to download apk file of project to third device (I think that is also android 4.3) and notifications running without any problems.

Do you have any tips, what I should check on my device or in project? Thank you very much

PS: I have written android project in VS 2012, c# with Xamarin plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have a news in my case. I rebuilt APK file again, installed it and notifications working properly. But... I have two computers to deploying android applications. If I build APK installation file in first and then install it on cell phone, I cant deploy application properly from second PC to the same cell phone. Notifications stop working.

Now I know why notifications are not working and it is important!